# How to get the return value of a transaction instead of the transaction receipt in brownie

Tags: solidity, transactions, brownie

I have a function in my smart contract called `getRandomNumer`, and it returns a bytes32. However, in brownie, when I make a transaction it returns the transaction receipt.

How do I get the return value?

```
requestId = vrf_consumer.getRandomNumber(get_seed, {'from': accounts[0]})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tx.return_value` in the transaction receipt or make a `.call` request.

`.call` which will simulate the transaction going through. Just to note, if you send the transaction again, and then call `.call` again, it will be different. Here are some examples;

`requestId` is the transaction receipt:

```
requestId = vrf_consumer.getRandomNumber(get_seed, {'from': accounts[0]})
```

`requestId` is the requestId (returned value):

```
requestId = vrf_consumer.getRandomNumber.call(get_seed, {'from': accounts[0]})
```

Comment: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html?highlight=.call#ContractTx.call

simulating transactions isn't always useful in tests. `tx.return_value` can be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use [TransactionReceipt.return_value](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html?highlight=.call#TransactionReceipt.return_value)

```py
tx = vrf_consumer.getRandomNumber(get_seed, {'from': accounts[0]})
request_id = tx.return_value
```